# Xilinx VHDL latch warning troubleshooting

Tags: warnings, vhdl, xilinx, synthesis

Xilinx is inferring a latch for a VHDL code i've written. I've looked up the possible causes for this and found that it's often due to incomplete if or case statements. I've gone through and made sure to include else and when others statements, but i'm still receiving the warning. I believe this is also affecting another project i'm working on so i'd like to understand why this is the case.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity state_machine is
    port(trig, en: in std_logic; cstate,nstate: out std_logic_vector(0 to 2)); 
end state_machine;

architecture Behavioral of state_machine is
signal cstate_s,nstate_s: std_logic_vector(0 to 2);

begin
cstate <= cstate_s;
nstate <= nstate_s;

process(en, cstate_s)
begin
    if en = '1' then
        nstate_s <= "111";
        if cstate_s = "111" then
            nstate_s <= "011";
        elsif cstate_s = "011" then
            nstate_s <= "100";
        elsif cstate_s = "100" then
            nstate_s <= "101";
        elsif cstate_s = "101" then
            nstate_s <= "110";
        elsif cstate_s = "110" then
            nstate_s <= "111";
        else
            null;
        end if;
    else
        null;
    end if;
end process;

process(trig, nstate_s)
begin
    if rising_edge(trig) then
        cstate_s <= nstate_s;
    else
        null;
    end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

> WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 3-bit latch for signal . Latches may
>   be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not
>   recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to
>   timing problems.

Comment: Your if statement priority encoder/multiplexer for nstate_s is incomplete. You cover condition values "011",  "100", "101", "110", and "111"  and have an else statement that's a null statement. That means for condition values "000", "001", and "010" you will not driver a different value on nstate_s defining latches. Change the else case to driver the current values of cstate_s. The else null is superfluous in the cstate_s register which holds the value set on the rising edge of trig. You should be able to go through your design career without ever using a null statement.

Comment: The only values used in synthesis are binary representing values ('0', '1', 'L' and 'H' mapped to '0' and '1', while 'Z' is used to infer high impedance state). An else  (or case others choice) should cover binary values for synthesis and all unspecified values for simulation. The two uses are not incompatible. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.8.2 Interpretation of the standard logic types. Statements specifying metalogical values (U', 'X', 'W', and '–' ) are ignored in synthesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For there to be no latches synthesised when a *combinational* process is synthesised, there must be no path between `begin` and `end process;` where all the outputs of the process are not assigned. This is called *complete assignment*. An output of the process is any `signal` assigned anywhere within it.

You have such paths. When any path with your `null` statements are executed, the output of your first process (`nstate_s`) is not assigned to. Therefore, you will get latches synthesised. There is no point in just having a `null` statement. If you genuinely don't care what value is assigned to your outputs in these paths, assign the outputs to `'-'`, which means *don't care* in VHDL.

By the way (assuming `trig` is a clock), your second process is not combinational (it is *sequential*) and so you don't need to obey complete assignment; your `else` branch is unnecessary.